# What question or answer that you have posted to the main site are you most proud of

Tags: discussion, specific-question, promotion, meta, answers

I figure, what's a Meta site without a good meta question.

What have you posted (and maybe a little why) that you really feel proud about. Is it something that you feel especially knowledgable about? Is it something with deep meaning to you? Are you just thrilled that the response got you über rep points?

Please include links to the q/a.

Just curious. Will post mine if people like the meta topic.

Answer (score 6):

[**My answer to the origin of Joker**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1428/what-is-the-real-reason-for-the-jokers-clown-makeup-in-the-dark-knight/1429#1429)

---

It is obvious from my profile pic that I am an avid lover of the Nolan Batman Universe.  But nothing more so than the portrayal of the *chaotic* Joker.  He is, in my mind, the perfect villain.  **Never** having any regrets or second thoughts about what he does.  Always having a sound strategy, and is always someone to be feared of, even when he is in the clutches of the Dark Knight himself.

The fact that he is the way he is should be enough for anyone to fear him with every fiber of their being.  But what is most important about him is the fact that *no one* has *any* idea of **why** he is the way he is.  It is a complete mystery to Batman, Oracle, the writers; even the Joker himself has no idea why he is the way he is.

I feel Ledger captured this perfectly across the movie and actually *allowed me to like him as an actor*.   Not because the role essentially killed him, but because he brought that chaotic character to life in a way unimaginable to most.

While it may speak odd things about my character, but Joker is one of my favorite characters to come out of any written media because of these reasons and I feel proud knowing enough to share my love for this character in answer form, and I also have plenty to still learn about him and his various alias' (upon my 3rd viewing of Dark Knight, I realized that Melvin White is one of the alias' he used during the comics; for example)

Most of my love for Joker comes back to a childhood question I had while watching the typical cartoons wondering "why does the hero always win?"  Being introduced to the Joker for the first time was a happy moment, discovering a villain that didn't just get beaten in the end, but no matter what, had the last laugh.  This was furthered for me when I learned of the *Jason Todd* arc of the Batman comics when it was decided (by the readers, but still powerful regardless) that Joker had *killed* Robin (Jason Todd at the time; though he would come back as Red Hood, Joker's first known criminal alias, in a strike of irony).

---

While this answer is not wholly representative of my Joker knowledge, I feel proud of it being a highly voted-answer and hopefully spark some more readers interest into Joker mythos, and appreciation for one of the most perfect villains conceived by man.

Comment: regarding the profile pic, I never looked close enough to notice that it's Joker

Comment: @Tshepang yes, one of my favorite pics I found.  Ledger minus the full make up, just the scars.  It looks so creepily like myself that I just had to.

Answer (score 5):

[**My answer to the Dead Poets Society question**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/612/is-john-keating-to-blame-for-neils-suicide)

---

As I mentioned in my answer, I was in summer stock when that film was released. The Summer Stock was a college internship program. So it wasn't merely theatre for pay but theatre for pay for studies.

I remember how stunned we all were with Robert Sean Leonard's performance overall, but in the Midsummer scene we were all dumbstruck. (To this day, I'd happily give money to see him play the full role.)

I remember the argument with the father very clearly having had that exact same argument with my parents earlier that year over the exact same thing. I wanted to leave a math/sciences major to devote myself entirely to Theatre. My parents acquiesced after seeing me do a performance of Skelly Manor in "Rimers of Eldrich." Watching Neil get pushed around was very hard for me and the friends (cast mates) that I watched it with.

The most distinct moment for me was the moment before Neil was asked if he was going to give up theatre. Robert Sean Leonard managed to make the light in his eyes go dead. The actor convincingly portrayed someone killing their own soul. One friend and I leaned over to each other and said, "He just killed himself." It was actually very spooky that we both said the same thing together. I supposed it's a sign of a good cast who know each other so well.

As mentioned the actual suicide felt like it was for the people who didn't really follow what happened in the argument.

The bunch of us went back to our college dorms (where we were housed for the show) and stayed up most the night drinking and discussing Neil's suicide. One of my senior papers was on the topic.

So when I saw the question, it was like all of that came back. However this time it included 20 yrs of experience (both theatre and life) and let me see the topic again anew. I even picked up on new concepts that we missed the first time. (Like the parallels to the symbolism of the character being Puck)

It's a topic that means a lot to me and I'm pleased that my answer was well received.

Answer (score 4):

I think the question I'm most proud of is [What's with the dead characters at the end of V For Vendetta](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/whats-with-the-dead-characters-at-the-end-of-v-for-vendetta).  It was a question that I had on my initial viewing of the movie, and never quite understood that part of the movie.  Upon rewatching the movie I was again stumped by this part, and I promptly asked the question.  I feel that it's a great question because it's something that's not inherently obvious to a lot of people, but adds a decent amount of understanding to the movie.

Comment: Agreement here.  I always assumed the girl's death was fake.  It was upon my third viewing did I realize that there were other dead characters in the crowd.

Answer (score 4):

Answers to two questions come to mind, neither of which is about Inception which seems to be the movie I have answered more questions about.

[My answer to: Why is the Salieri-Mozart relationship projected falsely in the movie Amadeus?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/702/40)

The reason I like this question as it is about historical accuracy in a movie.  Movies like plays are largely stand alone works of art - they don't have to be historically accurate (Amadeus) or faithful to source material (Blade Runner) to be great work of art in their own right.  Amadeus is not a documentary it is a (slightly comedic) drama about genius and it was great to answer a question about a movie that doesn't get a lot of attention nowadays.

[My answer to: Subconsciously influencing the audience with single frames](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/1003/40)

I enjoyed answering this question as I had to do some research.  I presumed before I looked into this that there was some sort of evidence supporting subliminal advertising, so it was a surprise to find that it was all an urban legend.  I wish I could have found some more concrete sources, but to reference snopes was kind of fun.

Comment: Yes, I know I cheated and put two ..... if pushed I would go with the Amadeus one.

Comment: We'll just tar and feather you :p

Answer (score 4):

Even though I have provided some answers that I consider quite good, the achievement I am most proud of would probably be a question:

[What significance does Mike Yanagita have in Fargo?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/290/what-significance-does-mike-yanagita-have-in-fargo)

This is a question that imho really shows the value of this site. I felt that something was off with this character and that there had to be some meaning to it, but was unable to figure it out.

So I put it up here as a question and a short time later Shawn Holmes provided this great analysis that gave me, and probably a lot of other people who just took Yanagita for granted as an meaningless subplot, a deeper understanding of this marvelous movie.

This kind of uncovering analysis is the reason I love m&tv, the reason I come here so often. And the fact that my question helped provide one of these "aha experiences" is the reason I am proud of it.

Comment: agreed, that question's thread is one of my favorites on the site!

Answer (score 1):

My answer to [How do they film the mirror scenes in movies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/how-do-they-film-the-mirror-scenes-in-movies/2191#2191) is the best upvoted answer for me. None of my other question answer got this much up vote so i am kind of proud of it.

And my Best Question for me is is [What is the reason for choosing Mary Jane over the Gwen Stacy in the 2002 Spider-Man movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2427/what-is-the-reason-for-choosing-mary-jane-over-the-gwen-stacy-in-the-2002-spider) .